# DataWeave 1.0 lower function is not working as expected

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have a below function that checks for the string and removes the value.
It works fine when the string matches the case accurately. I tried to add lower to check for both possibilities in a given string. but it is not working as expected.

If the payload contains a value from `filterList` it removes only the key and value that matches exactly as `"phone"`. But, the expectation is to remove if key/value has "phone","Phone","secondaryPhone" etc

Input:

```
{
    "phone":"123-234-9872",
    "Type":"Phone",
    "aType": ["T1", "T2"]
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
    "aType": ["T1", "T2"]
}
```

Script:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json skipNullOn="everywhere"
     
%function remove(content, filterList)
        content match {
            :array -> $ map (value,index) -> remove(value, filterList),
            :object -> $ mapObject (value,key) ->
                (key): null when (filterList contains (lower key as :string))
                    otherwise remove(value, filterList)
                ,
            default -> null when ((content !=null) and (filterList contains content as :string)) otherwise content
        }
---
remove(payload,["phone","email","accountNumber"])
```

Comment: please provide what is the input and expected output

Comment: Please add the body of the script with the call to the function so it is complete.

Comment: @aled updated the question with complete script

Comment: The title seems confusing. What does scope and multiple functions have to do with the question? It looks more like how to remove multiple keys from an object.

Comment: @aled There is no problem in removing the keys or values. I am facing an issue when using contains along with lower. so, thought of having that as a title

Comment: That has no relationship to scope and multiple functions.

Comment: For future questions try to include an input that covers all important cases to validate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the condition used for default doesn't include changing the case of the content. The condition is also a bit complex because the script is not using `match` to consider the case for when content is a string. Using the full power of pattern matching simplifies the evaluation.

```js
%dw 1.0
%output application/json skipNullOn="everywhere"
     
%function remove(content, filterList)
        using (lowerFilters=filterList map (lower $)) (content match {
            :array -> $ map (value,index) -> remove(value, lowerFilters),
            :object -> $ mapObject (value,key) ->
                (key): null when (lowerFilters contains (lower key as :string))
                    otherwise remove(value, lowerFilters)
                ,
            :string -> null when (lowerFilters contains (lower content)) otherwise content,
            default -> content
        })

---
remove(payload,["phone","email","accountNumber"])
```

An additional improvement is to use a local variable that lowers also the items in `filterList`. For example `"accountNumber"` would not match even when the actual value is `"accountnumber"` in the original version.

Comment: Updated to lower the values in `filterList`.

Comment: Thanks! it works perfectly after the second update.